# kafka jmx metrics observed output byte higher than input byte

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring, jmx

To monitor the Kafka Matrix, I created a monitoring tool that loads values into the Java API.

The "BytesInPerSec" and "BytesOutPerSec" are collected and the difference is calculated to check the status of the Kafka.

By the way when monitoring Kafka is often observed that the output metrics is higher than the input metrics. The difference of value is not small, and there is a big difference.

Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: Well, clearly multiple consumers are reading the topic... This isn't exactly a good status check other than data is being transferred

Comment: @Mickael Maison kafka version is kafka 2.11-0.11.0.1 and Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @cricket_007  Hmm... There are times when the same Phenomenon appears even if 1 consumer and 1 producer run.

Comment: I can't remember if that metric includes outgoing bytes for replication or not